# Sum values from rows ignoring certain values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a follow-up on this question: [Sum values from rows with conditions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68201322/sum-values-from-rows-with-conditions-in-r)

Here is my data:

```
ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
Q1 <- c(0, 1, 7, 9, NA, 3) 
Q2 <- c(0, 3, 2, 2, NA, 3) 
Q3 <- c(0, 0, 7, 9, NA, 3) 

dta <- data.frame(ID, Q1, Q2, Q3)
```

I need to sum every value below 7, but in lines with values over 7, I need to sum all the numbers below 7 and ignore the ones over it. Rows with all NAs should be preserved. Result should look like this:

```
ProxySum
0
4
2
2
NA
9
```

I have tried this code based on the response from the last post:

```
dta2  <- dta %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(ProxySum = ifelse(all(c_across(Q1:Q3) < 7), Reduce(`+`, c_across(Q1:Q3)), (ifelse(any(c_across(Q1:Q3) > 7), sum(.[. <  7]), NA))))
```

But in the rows with numbers over 7 I end up with a sum of all the rows and columns. What I am missing?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't work - you need quotes around the letters and `NA` needs to be capitalized.

Comment: Adding to @GregorThomas comment.  Please mind the coding style: spaces after comma, lower-case names for vars, no space between function name and opening bracket, pipes are designed to make code more readable - place your calls after the pipe to a new line, nested `ifelse` calls are confusing. Also, you don't need to create variables, and than call `data.frame()` with them. It's fine to do it as `data.frame(x = ..., y = ...)`. You don't need `as.data.frame()` but `data.frame()` instead.

Comment: Nattys, don't worry too much about those styling suggestions - although useful, they are not exactly necessary. regarding `as.data.frame` - please try this in your console check what it returns. If you want to use `as.data.frame` (which you can), you should do `as.data.frame(list(ID,Q1,Q2,Q3))`

Comment: @tjebo styling is not necessary for the evaluation of the code, but quite important for readability. Clear way of asking the question, is a half-way to the right answer.  I don't see how e.g. last line of the code is clear, and why it is better than clearly formatted code. The fact that someone *can* do something, does not mean one *should* do it.  There is no reason to wear your pants over your head, as well as to  use `as.data.frame()` and extra variable assignments here. Doing something you are not supposed to do, just because you can do it, is the definition of sin :).

Comment: Thank you all for the styling tips, I will pay more attention to that, I know readability is important. As for the ID column without quotes, you are right, I forgot to add them when I created the example. I am not a very experienced user and still commit many mistakes

Comment: @nattys, it's absolutely fine, you are learning, mistakes are the best teachers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it in `base`:

```
rowSums(dta[, 2:4] * (dta[, 2:4] < 7))

# [1]  0  4  2  2 NA  9
```

---

Adding explanation, according to @tjebo comment

- With `dta[, 2:4] < 7` you produce a dataframe populated with `logical` values, where `TRUE` or `FALSE` corresponds to the values which are *less* or *greater* than `7`. It is possible to do in one line, since this operation is vectorized;
- Than, you multiply above *logical* dataframe, and a dataframe populated with your original values. Under the hood, R converts `logical` types into `numeric` types, so all `FALSE` and `TRUE`s from your *logical* dataset, are converted to `0`s and `1`s. Which means that you multiply your original values by `1` if they are *less* than `7`, and by `0`s otherwise;
- Since `NA < 7` produces `NA`, and following multiplication by `NA` will produce `NA`s as well - you preserve the original `NA`s;
- Last step is to call `rowSums()` on a resulting dataframe, which will sum up the values for each particular row. Since those of them that exceed `7` are turned into `0`s, you exclude them from resulting sum;
- In case, when you want to get a sum for the rows where *at least one value is not `NA`*, you can use `na.rm = TRUE` argument to your `rowSums()` call. However, in this case, for the rows with `NA`s *only* you will get `0`.

Comment: Just want to comment that I added your code to mutate in order to create another column. Here is the code I used in case others are interested:   `dta2 <- dta %>% mutate(ProxySum = rowSums(dta[, 2:4] * (dta[, 2:4] < 7)))`

Comment: With this code you can also use *native pipes* (`|>`) introduced since R4.01 .

Answer (score 3):

How about a slightly different approach - first pivot longer, then sum by condition by group, then pivot back.

In this current version, rows that contain only "some" NAs will return a value other than NA. (NA will be considered as 0). If you want to return NA for those rows, change `all` to `any`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ID <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
Q1 <- c(0,1,7,9,NA,3) 
Q2 <- c(0,3,2,2,NA,3) 
Q3 <- c(0,0,7,9,NA,3) 

dta <- data.frame(ID,Q1,Q2,Q3) 

dta %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ProxySum = ifelse(all(is.na(value)), NA, sum(value[which(value<7)]))) %>%
  pivot_wider()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#> # Groups:   ID [6]
#>   ID    ProxySum    Q1    Q2    Q3
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A            0     0     0     0
#> 2 B            4     1     3     0
#> 3 C            2     7     2     7
#> 4 D            2     9     2     9
#> 5 E           NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 6 F            9     3     3     3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Another option making use of `rowSums` and `dplyr::across`:

```r
ID <- LETTERS[1:6]
Q1 <- c(0,1,7,9,NA,3) 
Q2 <- c(0,3,2,2,NA,3) 
Q3 <- c(0,0,7,9,NA,3) 

dta <- data.frame(ID,Q1,Q2,Q3) 

library(dplyr)

dta %>% 
  mutate(ProxySum = rowSums(across(Q1:Q3, function(.x) { .x[.x >= 7] <- 0; .x })))
#>   ID Q1 Q2 Q3 ProxySum
#> 1  A  0  0  0        0
#> 2  B  1  3  0        4
#> 3  C  7  2  7        2
#> 4  D  9  2  9        2
#> 5  E NA NA NA       NA
#> 6  F  3  3  3        9
```

Comment: I'd probably add `na.rm = TRUE`, but this depends of course on what the OP wants to do with NAs (in my solution I didn't bother to much with this as the OP did not specify what should happen)

Comment: @tjebo the OP stated they want the NAs preserved.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover thanks - I overlooked that, and have updated my answer accordingly. It's still unclear how the OP wants to deal with rows that contain only "some" NAs.

Comment: @tjebo Good point concerning `NA`s, somehow I missed it.

Comment: @tjebo, in my data the NAs are coded as 7, so there are no NAs, except for the IDs that have no answers, like ID E in my example

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** See @tjebo comment of identical solution as stefan:

Here is a non identical solution: using `hablar`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)

dta %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sum = sum_(across(Q1:Q3, ~case_when(.<7 ~sum_(.)))))
```

**First answer:** Possible identical to stefan's answer:

Here is another `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
dta %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ifelse(.>=7,0,.)),
         sum = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))
```

```
  ID Q1 Q2 Q3 sum
1  A  0  0  0   0
2  B  1  3  0   4
3  C  0  2  0   2
4  D  0  2  0   2
5  E NA NA NA  NA
6  F  3  3  3   9
```

Comment: this is essentially the same as Stefan's code, but in two lines?

Comment: Hmmh. You might be right! I upvoted all answers, since I tried quite long to solve it without following any solution before. My first try was `dta %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(Q1:Q3, ~ifelse(.<7 & sum(is.na(.)==0),sum(.), NA))) %>% 
  mutate(sum = sum(across(Q1:Q3, ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE))))` .But this solution did not account the NA. So all in all I think it is worth to leave my answer as it is declared as another (in your word [one with more lines] solution). Moreover in terms of readability it is worth to give it a change. What do you think?

Comment: Of course, leave both suggestions! I didn’t know hablar, thanks for sharing. Generally,  I think that answers do not necessarily need to be totally different, but if they are very very similar, one should point out more clearly how this is different. I agree your version is more readable!